# Extremely Slow Wordpress WooCommerce website (Both in admin panel and end user)

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, iis, woocommerce

I have a woo-commerce plugin installed within IIS 8 hosted in a shared windows hosting environment along with roughly 27-8 plugins related to my theme (Porto Theme) and some other functionalities. Unfortunately, I have a very slow response when adding/editing a Product or even visiting the website.(It takes about 25s or so to edit or add a product!)

I was wondering what could be the problem here. Some said this is due to the fact that you are hosting Wordpress on a windows server. So I did try this configuration within a Linux server, didn't make a dent!(it got even slower!)

This is my configuration for the windows case:

```
max_execution_time 180
memory_limit 128M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

My database is very light (around 30MB). I have also tried wt3 cache, autoptimizer, and minifications plus defering of javascript.

I tried this setting in Windows VPS, it got twice as fast as the shared hosting environment. But my shared hosting company is a reputable one and has some standard Memory and CPU allocations.

No Luck so far in finding the problem ... Is Woocommerce generally a heavy plugin or something?

Comment: the wordpress / woocommerce structure is currently not the fastest of all due to the "blogging" architecture of Wordpress.. I use it all the time though,, I personally think that the "ton" of plugins that are in place are slowing down the site.. did you try disabling them all and re-enabling one by one? 

Maybe moving to Linux Server could also help, I know that lots of companies run PHP on windows.. but somehow it feels weird.

Comment: You're always going to be limited by a shared host. And I found that updating to PHP7 made a huge difference for me. I agree with funkysoul that you may have too many plugins, or at least one that is really dragging you down. Sometimes they "phone home" to check for updates and that can really slow things down. Or as mentioned below, it could be your theme. I've found a lot of ThemeForest themes to be terribly frustrating to work with.

Comment: @funkysoul Yes, I actually did. Disabling all plugins -> managed to half the response time. By changing the theme from Porto to another, I somehow can get to a better result (ranging from 5s to 8s, which is acceptable).
When I enable all the plugins again, with a defaut theme, still low response time. So, overall I think it is a problem of both theme and some plugins. Trying to figure out the exact one.

Comment: @helgatheviking yeah, I know. But I assume there shouldn't be a performance issue for a website of 30MB DB. That should hit us at a further time.

Comment: If all the plugins + Twenty Sixteen is still slow, then I would suggest testing the plugins one at a time to try to find the source. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the issue is WooCommerce as I have several sites that run it in various environments with plenty of speed. It's a well-built plugin.

I also don't think that the issue is related to the *number* of plugins you are running, but possibly about one or more of those being inefficient. I would follow the previous commenter's advice about disabling them all and then re-activate one at a time.

The issue could also very well be the theme you are using - Porto. I took a quick look at user comments on the theme's main sales page and several users reported it as having some slowness issues. If you have the Envato plugin installed, disable that. If you are not using the most recent version of the theme, try upgrading. And if none of that works, try switching to a different theme and see if that fixes it. I've unfortunately had to ditch paid themes in the past due to their developers not putting the time into maximizing performance and efficiency. It stinks, but a slow front and back end does no good for anyone.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the on suspect I need to do something about. Probably need to change the theme or otherwise upgrade the hosting service.

Comment: Just as recommendation to check how the speed / performance behaves... Have a try with the storefront theme (woocommerce official theme) there you can be pretty sure that things work the way they should.

Comment: @funkysoul Weird, doesn't even work with Storefront... It works with "Twenty Fourteen" (Wordpress Default theme) though. Not sure how to perceive this behavior. I'm pretty sure the hosting service isn't low in config. I have an "Orchard" CMS running in the main domain with no issue at all.

Comment: Another Update: Twenty Fourteen theme + All plugins being enabled, It gets worse (still better than Porto + all Plugin enabled).

Comment: Final Update: I finally found out that the problem is with the theme (Porto) and some other plugins related to theme. Since I didn't have time to change the theme, I had to upgrade my hosting service. Now, I'm running woocommerce on a linux shared hosting with "5G of RAM and 5 CPU Cores"!